# Asio Compiler errors (Win7 64 Bit + VC11)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost-asio

a few days ago I upgraded from Win7 32Bit + Visual Studio 2008 to Win7 64Bit + Visual Studio 2012 (VC11). Now I have problems with compiling my application. I get the following errors:

```
1>...\asio-1.5.3\include\asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(51): error C2664: 'QueueUserAPC': cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(ULONG)' to 'PAPCFUNC'
1>...\asio-1.5.3\include\asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp(119): error C2664: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': cannot convert parameter 3 from 'DWORD *' to 'PULONG_PTR'
1>...\asio-1.5.3\include\asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp(349): error C2664: 'GetQueuedCompletionStatus': cannot convert parameter 3 from 'DWORD *' to 'PULONG_PTR'
```

And I get the same errors with the latest version of boost::asio (Boost 1.52)

What’s wrong here?

Comment: post your application code demonstrating the problem

Comment: This will happen when you target a very old version of Windows, older than Windows 2000.  Set the WINVER macro to at least 0x500.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - with WINVER set to 0x0501 it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with WINVER set to 0x0501 it's working - Many Thanks to Hans Passant for his hint!